# Installing a cocoapod and 'github' asks for login credentials?

Tags: ios, phishing

I just added a cocoapod and got this

```
>ls
Podfile             superApp
Podfile.lock        superApp.xcodeproj
Pods                superApp.xcworkspace
>pod install

Updating local specs repositories
Username for 'https://github.com': Password for 'https://github.com': 
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
```

That github prompt is fishy (/phishy). I entered a bogus email and no password and it started downloading.

Any ideas?

Comment: so, it logs into github to download - that's not surprising

Comment: I didn't enter a password @schroeder